# Apply image width to <figure> tag

Tags: images, block-editor

Before the Block Editor was implemented, the `<figure>` tag used to have an inline *width* styling, matching the value of the image inside, example:

```
<figure style="width:300px;">
    <img src="https://example.com/image.jpg" width="300" height="100">
    <figcaption> text </figcaption>
</figure>
```

But since the Block Editor, this inline styling is removed:

```
<figure>
    ...
</figure>
```

How can we add this inline width styling back to the `<figure>` tag (*avoiding* a jQuery approach)?

Comment: Why? Or: what is it you are trying to achieve with this? Setting it to `display: inline-block;` might already solve many problems

Comment: I was just about to ask and suggest the exact same thing.  I don't know if there is an easy way to do this without recreating the block, although there may be.

Comment: @kero @RiddleMeThis This is one of the cases where a simply `display: inline-block;` won't resolve it unfortunately.

Comment: Could you do it similar to [this solution](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/317576/gutenberg-get-all-attributes-from-core-image-block)? I've been trying with a pure JS method but cannot get the store working (`blocks.getSaveElement` filter gets URL and ID as third argument, but I've been unable to query given that ID to get the size)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming you want this value on the front-end as opposed to needing it in the block editor due to the `<figure>` somehow not displaying correctly when viewed in the block editor.

If that is the case then you can use something similar to `DOMDocument` as per the following example:

#### Assume HTML of:

```
<div>
    <figure>
        <img src="https://example.com/image.jpg" width="300" height="100">
        <figcaption> text </figcaption>
    </figure>
    <figure>
        <img src="https://example.com/image.jpg" width="300" height="100">
        <figcaption> text </figcaption>
    </figure>
    <figure>
        <img src="https://example.com/image.jpg" width="300" height="100">
        <figcaption> text </figcaption>
    </figure>
</div>
```

#### Processing logic:

```
$html = '<!-- YOUR HTML -->';

libxml_clear_errors();
$libxml = libxml_use_internal_errors(true);

$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html);

$elements = $dom->getElementsByTagName('figure');

foreach ($elements as $element) {
    foreach ($element->getElementsByTagName('img') as $img) {
        if ( $img->hasAttribute('width') ) {
            $width = $img->getAttribute('width');
            $element->setAttribute('style', "width:{$width}px;");
        }
    }
}

libxml_clear_errors();
libxml_use_internal_errors($libxml);

// for debugging purposes print out the modified HTML
echo $dom->saveHTML();
```

> Feel free to add more conditional guards/checks for existing style attributes so you can append/parse accordingly as my example shows a basic use-case only to get you started assuming this method is suitable for you.

#### Resulting output `$dom->saveHTML()`:

```
<div>
    <figure style="width:300px;">
        <img src="https://example.com/image.jpg" width="300" height="100">
        <figcaption> text </figcaption>
    </figure>
    <figure style="width:300px;">
        <img src="https://example.com/image.jpg" width="300" height="100">
        <figcaption> text </figcaption>
    </figure>
    <figure style="width:300px;">
        <img src="https://example.com/image.jpg" width="300" height="100">
        <figcaption> text </figcaption>
    </figure>
</div>
```

Notes:

- you could filter the content and/or resulting template prior to rendering on client via `the_content` and or similar
- you could optionally filter the content prior to save via `save_post`

LibXML/DOMDocument:

Due to issues with processing HTML5, `DOMDocument` will generate warnings as a result of errors raised within libxml. Word on the street is that these are fine to suppress however I was only able to suppress them via using:

- libxml_clear_errors();
- libxml_use_internal_errors();
- libxml_clear_errors();
- libxml_use_internal_errors();

Alternatively you could use `@` suppresion on:

- `@$dom->loadHTML($html);`

...which is a little cleaner than the verbosity of four extra function calls.

Apparently this should work (since it was fixed):

`$doc->loadHTML($html, LIBXML_NOWARNING);`

...however I was unable to get this constant to work (could be version issues etc), see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6090667/php-domdocument-errors-warnings-on-html5-tags) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41844778/php-libxml-nowarning-not-suppressing-warnings).

Comment: This is great @userabuser - I am yet to test it out, but the code makes perfect sense. I would probably add a check to see whether if the `<figure>` tag may already have the width statement added. My initial hopes was to find a way to hook into the block code and add the styling there (so it is implemented naturally), but the fallback was `DOMDocument` so thank you very much for posting this solution!

Comment: @ChristineCooper you are welcome, let us know how you get on or if you need further help. I'd be interested to know, if you end up using `save_post` hook before insertion, if the editor does not parse out the attributes on load (I'd assume not).

Comment: Ended up solving it via a bizarre CSS approach which I never anticipated. Anyway, accepting this one!