# Modified core/image rendering not showing in posts - only on pages

Tags: posts, customization, images

I followed this suggestion to slightly [modify the rendering of the core/image block](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/326099).

This works perfectly for images on pages. But I need the same rendering also in posts. But the method above does not seem to influence how posts are rendered. Do I have to register my block rendering specifically for posts somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

False alarm: It *is* working also in post - I had wrongly looked at an example of an inline image, which - of course - is not of type core/image.

Sorry.