# Modify src attribute on image block

Tags: block-editor

Been googling like crazy but come up empty. Is it possible to modify the src attribute with the core image block? I want to replace `src` with `data-src` for lazy loading images without the native functionality.

Comment: Native lazy losing is now supported in all major browsers, so there’s no reason to do this.

Comment: @JacobPeattie I kind of agree, however, the native lazy is not as flexible/tweakable as a custom lazy function can be.

Answer (score 0):

You want to take a look at the Codex about [Block Filters](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/filters/block-filters/).

You'll need to make a filter using `add_filter` and hook into `render_callback` by re-registering `core/image` and modifying the render callback.

Checkout this [WPSE post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/326099/218062) from [uruk](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/40821/uruk).

Comment: Nice, I'll try that out, thanks!